# Firefox show title attribute only once

Tags: javascript, firefox

When you move the mouse over a canvas I want it to show the coordinates.

When you change the mouse position (without move out of the canvas) I want it to show the new coordinates. A little delay would be nice.

I'm using a tooltip but this code in firefox doesn't work: the title appears only when you enter the canvas and then you have to move out and re-entering the canvas to show it again.

How can I solve?

```
document.getElementById('mycanvas').addEventListener(
    'mousemove', function(event) {
        mycanvas.title=event.layerX;
    });
```

Comment: I believe the `mouseover` event is more apt for your use case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseover

Comment: No, just now mousemove is working like mouseover and this is the problem :)

Comment: (`mousemove` is the correct event to track). I don't think you can have control over how the browser will display the canvas's *title*. Does this need to be the title? You can show coordinates wherever you want. For example, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xod00p9/4/). Do you want to show that in a kind of popover that would follow the mouse?

Comment: Yes, some kind of tooltip was the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control how the browser chooses to display an element's title. It's ["*usually displayed in a 'tool tip' popup when the mouse is over the displayed node*"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/title), but the delay to appear and how often it is updated is not under your control.

Below is an example that tracks mouse position and shows coordinates in a popup that you have total control over (delay to appear, offsets, style etc). Move your mouse over the canvas, wait a second on a given position to let the popup appear, move elsewhere, wait, etc.

Noteworthy details:

- Uses `setTimeout` at each `mousemove` event, and `clearTimeout` to clear previous one.
- Uses jQuery to "normalize" the event, using `pageX/pageY` and `$.offset()`, to place the tooltip itself at appropriate coordinates (taking into account window scrolling), and make it show coordinates that are relative to the canvas. (I placed the canvas within a div that has a 20px margin to show that).

<sub>(I initially wanted to do it without jQuery, but browser quirks about mouse event properties made me abandon that idea, and after multiple edits I settled with jQuery to get something working)</sub>

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var background = document.getElementById('background');
if (background.complete) context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
else background.onload = function() { context.drawImage(background, 0, 0); }
var caption = document.getElementById('caption');
var pos = {};
var timerID;
$(canvas).mousemove(function(e) {
  pos = {
    x: e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
    y: e.pageY - $(this).offset().top,
    captionX: e.pageX,
    captionY: e.pageY,
  };
  caption.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
  if (timerID) { clearTimeout(timerID); }
  timerID = setTimeout(showPosition, 500);
});
canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
  caption.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
  if (timerID) { clearTimeout(timerID); }
});
function showPosition() {
  caption.setAttribute('style', 'display: inline; left:'+(pos.captionX + 8)+"px; top: "+(pos.captionY + 8)+"px;");
  caption.innerHTML = "(" + pos.x + "," + pos.y + ")";
}
```

```css
#background {visibility:hidden;}
#caption {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 24px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 20px">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="caption"></div>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" id="background" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know which is the default style of the original (browser integrated) tooltip?

Comment: You have no access to that information, it's probably not even HTML/CSS, it depends on the browser, it might even use the OS's native widgets for the tooltip...